# s3 pre signed url expiring too soon

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am generating my presigned url in my aws lambda code like this. but rather then expiring after 5 years it's expiring like after 3,4 days. my code is

```
def get_presigned_get_url(object_name, expiration=3600 * 24 * 365 * 5):
    
    try:
        pre_signed_url = get_s3_client().generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': BUCKET_NAME,
                                                            'Key': object_name},
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL
    return pre_signed_url
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html#who-presigned-url) - the maximum is 7 days and may be less depending on how you authenticate the call.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum expiration time for presigned urls is one week from the time of creation (using CLI and SDK). So there is no way to have a presigned url without an expiration date.

I am not sure that we can increase the time duration for the presigned URL.

AWS Documentation: [AWS Documentation for Presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html)